# why is Mysql not accepting count(attribute1,attribute2)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried count(a1, a2) which gives me a Syntax error in Mysql. Can some one explain why is it not being accepted, when it is syntactically correct. And if accepted what would be the result.

Comment: Why are you trying to make count on both a1 and a2 ? A count is counting how many rows the select statement gets. Så it would be the same for both a1 and a2 in that statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count attribute contains only one one numeric filed if you use multiple filed with this then it will give you an syntax error so use only count(a1)

Answer (score 0):

you can not provide multiple element in count function parameter .

your code must me count(a1) , count(a2) not count(a1,a2)